# Excel Formula using IF and VLOOKUP Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

**CONTEXT**

I am trying to update the roster with new players in Sheet1 using data from Sheet2.  However, I am trying to only update the males roster info.  I have to first verify it is a new player and also that they are male to update the height.

The logic I applied was that `IF` you found "Yes", and that `VLOOKUP` returned "Male", then the cell should be populated with a formula that would then use ID # in a `VLOOKUP`.

**EXCEL SAMPLE**

```
*=IF(VLOOKUP("Yes",Sheet2!C2:D6, 2, FALSE) ="Male", "=VLOOKUP(A3, Sheet2!A2:D10, 2, FALSE)", "No")

Sheet1                                         Sheet2
ID #      Height                          ID#   Height      New       Gender    
100         No                            100    66"         No        Female      
101         *                             101    72"         Yes       Male       
102         No                            102    65"         Yes       Female
```

**PROBLEM**

The output of the * is `=VLOOKUP(A3, Sheet2!A2:D10, 2, FALSE)` in the cell.  Is there a way to get Excel to **actually evaluate and populate** that cell as if that was the original formula?

Comment: Use the `INDIRECT` function

Comment: @PeterT Could you provide some more detail please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're trying to look up multiple criteria, use `INDEX` with `MATCH` instead:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$4,MATCH(A3&"YesMale",INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4&Sheet2!$C$2:$C$4&Sheet2!$D$2:$D$4,),0)),"No")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply take it out of quotes, but even then I don't think you'll get quite what you want.

Try this:

```
= IF(
    AND(
        VLOOKUP(A3, Sheet2!$A$2:$D$10, 3, FALSE) = "Yes",
        VLOOKUP(A3, Sheet2!$A$2:$D$10, 4, FALSE) = "Male"),
    VLOOKUP(A3, Sheet2!$A$2:$D$10, 2, FALSE),
    "No")
```